# Learning about Running Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, virtualization

I want to learn about how to run a [Ubuntu Linux Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/WhatIsUbuntu/serveredition). Nothing too advanced. I simply want to learn about the basic setup and operation of a server to do the following things:

- SVN
- Apache Web Server (w/ PHP)
- FTP Server (for uploading files)
- MySql (*maybe*)

I want to get something running in [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/). Are there any introductory resources that someone can point me to?  I know basic Linux commands but lets *assume* no other knowledge.

I've ran all of the above items on a Windows box. I'm familiar with each of their setup and administrations. The only thing I really don't understand is how to setup and configure each of the items from a command-line only interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [good book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590599233) from APress for a developer trying to learn how to setup and administer a Ubuntu server.  I am not sure it has information on installing and administering SVN, but it covers everything else you are interested in and does so without assuming a whole lot of prior knowledge.

Comment: This is probably my best option. I didn't know this existed. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The basic resources you'll end up going to are the [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/), [ubuntu help site](https://help.ubuntu.com/), and [community contributions help site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community).  All of those show up fairly high in google search results for questions with ubuntu in them.

In most cases, if you run into issues most of the time someone else already has and it is documented one of those places.

For your specific cases in the question:

[Subversion](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion)

[Apache and MySQL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)

[One FTP Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PureFTP)

There is also the more comprehensive: [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/C/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend [LPIC in a nutshell](http://bit.ly/fO5pM) to take your basic linux command knowledge from basic, to intermediate (if not advanced).  It's not an ubuntu server specific book but it does cover methods for Debian and Redhat and most of the information is distro independent.

Comment: I'm a software developer... This books seems like overkill and my start out over my head... You mention improvement of my command knowledge but I believe I'd need more infomration than that....